# Access GET parameter in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to AWS and I've just successfully setup a Lambda function with RDS connection. Now I'd like to access my new function from outside through the API gateway and passing a few arguments like: "color" : "red"

https://my-api-id.execute-api.region-id.amazonaws.com/flowers?**color=red**

I've setup everything following the [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-mappings.html) but unfortunately I'm not able to access the GET parameter in my Python Lambda function.

What I've done so far in my AWS API Gateway:

- Creating a resource "/flowers" and a GET method
- GET -> Method Request -> URL Query String Parameters -> Added "color"
- GET -> Integration Request -> Type: Lambda function
- GET -> Integration Request -> URL Query String Parameters -> Added `name: color`, `mapped: method.request.querystring.color`

I tried to access the `color` parameter in the lambda handler but the event is always empty and I don't know where the parameter are supposed to be otherwise

```
def handler(event, context):

    return event     // {}
```

I think I'm not able to use the *body mapping tamplates* unless I do not have a request body using GET.

Does anybody know what I need to do in my Python Lambda function, in order to access my `color` parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aws Api Gateway Integration Request How to append a property to request body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407161/aws-api-gateway-integration-request-how-to-append-a-property-to-request-body)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Correct me if I'm wrong but unless I've a GET request, I do not have any request body or even a content-type. I see that I can access the parameters in the the _Body Mapping Template_ using `$input.params('querystringkey')` but can you explain how I can access this data in my actual lambda function?

Comment: The best and standard way of accessing query string is using integration request only. Even AWS official documentation suggests that way only. Please have a look on 'Create a GET Method with Query Parameters to Call the Lambda Function' section in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html .Alternatively you can use other npm packages like 'querystring' (https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) to get query string, which is not official.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use *Lambda Proxy* as your integration request type.

And in your handler,

```
def handler(event, context):

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(event),
    }
```

Your query parameters should be accessible as `event['queryStringParameters']`.

Reference: [Set up a Proxy Resource with the Lambda Proxy Integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-set-up-lambda-proxy-integration-on-proxy-resource)